# How to delete a row in ag-Grid after server response is a success?

Tags: angular

I am working on ag-grid (is about different Industry/fields) and I have a delete button that I delete Industry, But I want to delete the Industry if the backend response is on success and not before because, when the backend sends an error message I still get the Industry deleted and I need to refresh to have it back to grid. From my point of view there can be two solutions:
1- if the backend sends an error I can get the Industry back (this seems very harder for me).
2- to delete after the backend response is ok, but I try playing with the code but I am very new with angular and I don't know how that can be done.
can anyone help me, please ??
So this is the code on administration.service.ts.

```
deleteIndustry(params: any[]): Observable<any> {
return this.http.post<any>(this.deleteIndustryListUrl, params)
  .pipe(
    map((res) => {
      return res;
    }),
  );

 }
```

this is the code on industry-list.component.ts.

```
  handleIndustryDataDelete(value: any) {
this.adminService.deleteIndustry(value)
  .subscribe(
    (data) => {
      this.industryDeleteResponse$ = data;
      this.updateMsg = 'Delete Successful';
      // console.log('Server-Response: ', this.industryDeleteResponse$);s
    },
    (error) => {
      // console.log('error', error);
      this.updateMsg = this.getErrorFromMessage(error);
    },
  );

}
```

So far the code works but it happens the problem I described above.
If you want me to provide more code please let me know.

Comment: Do you have access o gridapi ?

Comment: Why not using the complete callback? I mean, Angular has marked it as deprecated, but the HttpClient has complete callback, that ONLY works if the call was successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the answer in my comment; 
If you want to make sure your call was successful, you can use the complete callback.

```
this.httpClient.post(<some_url>, <data>).subscribe((data:any) => {
// something happens
}, (error) => {
// we catch an error here
}, () => {
// complete or success callback. If you want to make sure something only triggers when the call is successful, that's your callback. 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to delete the row, you can wait for the api call to finish. If its success, try to filter the industry row. Then use the gridapi to setRowData again

```
this.gridApi.setRowData(data);
```

Comment: how can i wait for the call to finished

Comment: You can wait by deleting the row in the subscribe method. Subscribe method will be called when api finishes. so your code to remove the row will be executed after the api inish